# query insert and select explaination

Tags: sql, mysql

I am confused about this query where it uses insert statement and then ignore and then select. Can someone explain me this? Thanks

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO
        myTable
    SELECT
        $var1  AS `CMMNCTID`,
        $var2  AS `ENCID`,
        variableID,
        ProductID,
        CustomerID,
        Age,
        "" AS `myJ`,
        "" AS `myI`
    FROM
        table2
    JOIN
        table3
    ON
        table2.ID= table3.ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SELECT` is a subquery. What the `INSERT` is doing is inserting whatever is contained in the join of `table2` and `table3`, into `myTable`. The `IGNORE` tells it to ignore any entries for keys that already exist in `myTable` and to just insert whatever doesn't yet exist.

It seems the purpose of the query is to combine the data that is associated between `table2` and `table3` and dump it into `myTable`.

Comment: usually insert statement has mysql insert into table(column1, column2) value(val, val2) but we dont see that here...why and how it knows where to insert

Comment: @user400749: The `AS ...` parts you see in the `SELECT` query correspond to the columns in `myTable`.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT IGNORE` in a keyword mysql: If the insert will cause a Primary key or Unique key error, it should skip that row.

`INSERT ... SELECT`: is used to copy data from another table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0):

It takes results from the `SELECT` query on tables table2 and table3 and inserts the results into table myTable. `IGNORE` keyword simply tells mysql to ignore any errors that occur while executing the INSERT query.